# Is unparsed content supported in nVelocity

Tags: nvelocity

When reading the [VTL reference for Velocity 1.7](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/vtl-reference-guide.html) at the bottom of the doc there was a reference to Unparsed content.

> Unparsed content is rendered at runtime, but is not parsed or interpreted.
>
> Example:
>
> #[[
>
> This has invalid syntax that would normally need "poor man's escaping" like:
>
> #define()
>      ${blah
>
> ]]#

I'm simply wondering if this is supported in nVelocity but not documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not implemented. Which means that you get to do it :-)

[Create an issue](http://issues.castleproject.org/dashboard), then [fork the repository](https://github.com/castleproject/NVelocity) and implement it, then send the team a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

It is supported. But I guess not the multi-line statement.

For example, this below is supported:

```
#[[ #define() ${blah ]]#
```

This is not:

```
#[[ 
    #define() ${blah 
]]#
```

Comment: Is it really implemented? I couldn't find any tests about it... can you point me to one? Or if it is supported and not tested, could you fork the repo and add a test?